# Swift: Index out of range in a 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am using a 2 dimensional array of String. When I init it, I fill it with a default value String. When I want to access an element from it, I get out of range errors

```
class MyClass: UIViewController, {

var bodies = [[String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setBodies()

    if isBodiesEmpty() {
        //setRefreshButton()
    }
}

private func setBodies() {
    var bodies = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: "default", count: 6), count: 4)

...

    bodies[2][0] = "string 2 0"
    bodies[2][1] = "string 2 1"

...

}

private func isBodiesEmpty() -> Bool {
    if bodies[2][0].isEmpty {
        return true
    }
    if bodies[2][0].contains("default"){ 
        return true
    }
    return false
}
}
```

Both

```
if bodies[2][0].isEmpty
```

and

```
if bodies[2][0].contains("default")
```

throw "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Yet if I print an element of my array, it works:

```
print("bodies[2][0] =="+bodies[2][0])
```

displays: "string 2 0"

There must be something trivial I overlooked but I dont know what

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's *something trivial* and a very common mistake. This line

```
var bodies = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: "default", count: 6), count: 4)
```

creates a **local** array `bodies` which is not the **property** `bodies`. Just delete `var`

```
bodies = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: "default", count: 6), count: 4)
```

Comment: Thank you @vadian, what a stupid mistake of mine. If a moderator wants to delete my question feel free, it won't add much value to global humankind intelligence